# Get Facebook Page ID from Instagram Id using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API and is it possible to get the linked facebook page from Instagram Business ID?

I am getting linked Instagram Business ID through Facebook Page ID by following Graph Query:
[https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage_id%7D?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

Result:

```
{
  "instagram_business_account": {
    "id": "1784140xxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "id": "5216610xxxxxxxx"
}
```

Same In reverse, I need Facebook Page ID through Instagram Business ID hence I am trying following Query but there's no parameter for page or owner

[https://graph.facebook.com/{instagram_business_account_id}?fields=page,owner&access_token={'access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Binstagram_business_account_id%7D?fields=page,owner&access_token=%7B%27access_token%7D)

Anyone can help me that how can get linked page id from Instagram
Business Account ID using API.